# Google map in javascript: Some markers don't have click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I have a problem when working with marker in Google map. 
A list of places that needs to appear on map, I create a loop for a all of them, every marker, I set a click event. But many (not all) markers don't have click event, I can't event click on them. Some markers still work. I don't know why, please help me, thanks so much. Here is my code.

```
// Store all markers
gMakers = [];

for (var key in places) {
  (function(key) {
    var location = {lat: Number(places[key].ln.lat), lng: Number(places[key].ln.lon)};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: location, map: map});

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
    gMakers.push(marker);
  })(key);
}
```

Comment: Which markers work? Always the same one's or is it intermittent?

Comment: seems the code is working fine for me... can you share the whole implementation ?

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is having too many markers, hundred of them.

Comment: @DNKROZ: always the same one's :((

Comment: @VigneshRaja: me too. Too many markers may be the problem, i think

Comment: Guys, I limit the number of markers down to 10, the problem still happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the posted code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x2y18vgd/)).  Perhaps it is a data issue. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
// Store all markers
gMakers = [];
    for (var key in places) {
  (function(key) {
    var location = {lat: Number(places[key].ln.lat), lng: Number(places[key].ln.lon)};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: location, map: map});

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
    gMakers.push(marker);
  })(key);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but it still happens, I think I have too many markers, hundreds of them, that's may the problem